# How to build a function that can visualize data of xlsx file system directly, plot and visualize it?

Tags: python-3.x, visualize

I am analizing and visualizing a rainfall historical data. The data file in xlsx contains data from 1993 to 2023. It am not able to visualize it.

I tried to use pandas but didn't find any this important out put. I tried to import file with these but couldn't

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cool project. Pandas has a built-in xlsx importer. Have you tried that? If so, toss in the code you've got so far. Might look something like this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('sample.xls')
```

If that didn't work you could also try converting the xlsx to a csv and then import that.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: Questions that are too broad to be answered _in full_ should be closed, not given partial answers. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer